# How to stop logs getting written in the terminal on linux

Tags: install4j

I made a installer on linux platform. When I install it throgh terminal by running the shell script then all the logs like sysout and error are getting printed in the terminal only. I don't want to get the logs on terminal. Please help how can I stop it.

Comment: The installer does not log to the terminal. The only output comes from the shell script as it tries to find a suitable JRE. What kind of logging output do you get?

Comment: It is writing all the system.out statements written in the custom code classes which has been put for the debugging purpose, though I have not enable the stderr/stdout. Even if it is enabledI think this creates the log at the app launch time not the installer launch time.  I have bundled the JRE so initially it logs for unpacking the JRE in the terminal  and  afterwards it start writing all the sysout statements present in the custom code classes.  Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
Starting Installer ...

Comment: Don't print to stdout but use Util.logInfo(null, "Your message"). See https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/Util.html

Comment: Okay, I will use Util.logInfo. Thanks!